# What is interoperability in microgrids?

Tags: microgrid

I have encountered the word "interoperability" in many papers with regards to "microgrids". However, there are no clear explanation for it. What does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 1):

In general interoperability reffers to the ability of different peices of equipment, usually that were designed/built by different companies, to operate together as part of a system.

Presumablly in the case of the microgrid system (disclaimer, I know nothing about microgrids other than what i've found from a quick google) this reffers to the devices that make up the microgrid operating together to maintain the desired behaviour even when the microgrid is built up with devices from a range of vendors.

Comment: I suppose this is as good an answer as the question itself suggests the OP is ready to receive. +1. By the way, there is a nice page that helped me understand what is, and what is not, a microgrid. Here: https://building-microgrid.lbl.gov/about-microgrids An increasingly interesting topic, broadly speaking, these days.